# Disable docker image being run as daemon (restart always policy)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemctl

Every time I start the docker daemon (via `systemctl start docker.service`), a bunch of images start running from a **docker-compose config** that I previously run.

How can I disable them from starting up when the docker daemon starts up?

I haven't been able to find any resources for this.

Answer (score 2):

Each container has a restart policy that stats what is about to happen when it terminates. [Here](https://blog.codeship.com/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy/) is an article about that. The following command gives you an overview of all of your containers with their restart policy:

```
docker inspect -f "{{.Name}} {{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}}" `docker ps -aq`
```

If you don't need these containers anymore removing them is probably the best solution. Therefore, you have to execute `docker-compose rm` with your compose file. You could also use `docker-compose stop` to indicate that you don't want the service around anymore.

Comment: "You could also use docker-compose stop to indicate that you don't want the service around anymore." will not prevent the containers from starting up again (on reboot).

Answer (score 2):

```
docker update --restart=no containerId
docker stop containerId
```

Replace `containerId` with the appropriate value